# Magento 2.3 Can't set a default value NULL in database table

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I want to add new column to wishlist table with type integer and default value NULL, but magento sets it as '0'. 
This is my db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="wishlist" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Wishlist main Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="new_column" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="true" identity="false"
                default="NULL" comment="Customer ID"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID" table="wishlist"
                    column="customer_id" referenceTable="customer_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id"
                    onDelete="CASCADE"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID" disabled="true"/>
        <index referenceId="WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID" indexType="btree">
            <column name="customer_id"/>
        </index>
    </table>
</schema>
```

I can edit default value as "NULL" in phpmyadmin, but I need Magento to do it automatically.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you performed setup:upgrade?

Comment: yes, shure. Column has been created, but with default value '0'

Comment: Please try this command 
`php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Your_Module`